# Invalid form key. please refresh the page. Discount code and Paypal review

Tags: magento2, error, paypal, discount, form-key

This one seems different to all the previous questions about this error message.

I'm getting the following message "Invalid form key. please refresh the page." when trying to enter a discount code or when getting to the paypal review step.

Also had a couple of admin logins fail where it just appears to refresh the page, no error given.

I'm on magento 2.3.1.

This is where it's happening when trying to use a discount code:
[image: This is where it's happening when trying a discount code]

Comment: are you on localhost?

Comment: @fmsthird nope, magemojo hosting